# Bundler-Audit: How to implement post-"bundle install" hook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, hook, bundler, gemfile

I recently discovered the [bundler-audit](https://github.com/postmodern/bundler-audit) gem, and I'm interested in creating a hook that runs bundler-audit after all of my normal bundler commands (install, update, etc).

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there may be a better approach, my current solution is to just use a bash function/alias.